# Sort retrieved YouTube videos from recent to old with postedAt

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, bots, youtube-data-api, discord.js

I want my Discord bot to retrieve few YouTube videos from a specific channel. Until there, that works fine, but I want it to retrieve from the recent one to the old one.

Here is my code:

```
    if(command === "meps") {
    var opts = {
        maxResults: 5,
        key: 'API KEY',
        channelId: 'UCcgvwZgeQIRQ-g9WDqgwXFw',
        type: 'video'
    };
    const lawMeps = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("lawAMV", "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-464n3t5gsuw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/csBjGhz51gY/s176-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg")
        .setDescription("Recent MEPs")
        .setThumbnail("https://yt3.ggpht.com/-464n3t5gsuw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/csBjGhz51gY/s176-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg")
        .setColor("#553B82");
    search('lawAMVs mep', opts, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        for (var resultCount = 0; resultCount < opts.maxResults; resultCount++) {
            var publishedAt = new Date(results[resultCount].publishedAt);
            if (results[resultCount].title.startsWith("MEP"))
            {
                lawMeps.addField(results[resultCount].title, results[resultCount].link + "\nPublished at: " + publishedAt, true);
            }
        }
        message.channel.send(lawMeps);
    });
}
```

And here the screen on how it looks: 
[image: how it looks]

Comment: If you're going to list videos in order by a certain criteria (date, rating, relevance, title, etc.), you need to use [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) as it has the date (Resources are sorted in reverse chronological order based on the date they were created) filter.

Comment: Already seen this. But even with this, i still don't get it tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's fixed guys.

I've just added this : `order: 'date',` between `maxResults: 5,` and the key line.

For some reasons it didn't worked before, but now it goes well ! :D